# Which of these control flows for TryParse is generally advised, if one over the other?

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I have a string `typeString`which I'm trying to parse to an Enum with 30 cases, all of which have rather unique return statements. In some books I have seen a control flow like this used

```
if (!Enum.TryParse(typeString, true, out replicatingInstrumentType))
{
    Log.Error("Unknown Replicating instrument type: " + typeString);
    return new EmptyInstrument(instrumentIdentifier, Currency.EUR);
}
switch (replicatingInstrumentType)
{
    case TypeA:
    {
        return TypeAReturnStatement;
    }

    // .....
    // more cases here ....
    // .....

    case TypeZ:
    {
        return TypeZReturnStatement;
    }
    default:
    {
        return new EmptyInstrument(instrumentIdentifier, Currency.EUR);
    }
}
```

whereas I've always figured one should do

```
if (Enum.TryParse(typeString, true, out replicatingInstrumentType))
{
    switch (replicatingInstrumentType)
    {
        case TypeA:
            {
                return TypeAReturnStatement;
            }

        // .....
        // more cases here ....
        // .....

        case TypeZ:
            {
                return TypeZReturnStatement;
            }
        default:
            {
                return new EmptyInstrument(instrumentIdentifier, Currency.EUR);
            }
    }
}

Log.Error("Unknown Replicating instrument type: " + typeString);
return new EmptyInstrument(instrumentIdentifier, Currency.EUR);
```

Besides the visual diference, is there any advantage/disadvantage over using one versus the other? Is there a consensus on which approach is better?

Comment: this is entirely opinion based.

Comment: Figured that might be the case, voting to close it as opinion-based then, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!Enum.TryParse(typeString, true, out replicatingInstrumentType))
{
    Log.Error("Unknown Replicating instrument type: " + typeString);
    return new EmptyInstrument(instrumentIdentifier, Currency.EUR);
}
```

Its called `Inverted IF` or [**Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses**](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html). Its just for easier readabilty as it reduces the number of nesting and indentation. Lesser the indentation increases your horizontal view area.

Comment: Personally, I hate this....but well, it's an opinion...

Comment: @Liam I hate when I find conditionals nested 3,4,5 levels deep when a few easy-to-find, easy-to-read guard statements could have just been placed at the top of the method. Likewise, just an opinion. To each their own. Either way, **consistency is the important issue here**.

Comment: There are no winners here... :)